# Как оценить процент подсчёта md5 в консоли?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, md5

Выполняю в консоли команду

```
tar -O -xvvzf sda2.tar.gz | md5sum -
```

Знаю размер архива (287 758 619 041 байт) и размер файла (731 766 587 392 байта).

Хочу понять прогресс подсчёта, но нигде не вижу объёма считанных/записанных данных (которые можно увидеть в Windows). Системный монитор Минта показывает только процессорное время. Как по нему можно оценить процент завершённости подсчёта?

[image: скриншот]

А может вё-таки есть возможность узнать объём считанных данных?

Comment: О! Стоило задать вопрос и он посчитался. Ура! Что-то типа 1:12:00 - 1:30:00 там в результате для gzip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно посмотреть в /proc/pid_of_tar/fdinfo/ в файле, соответствующем по имени симлинку в /proc/pid_of_tar/fd/, указывающему на архив.

То есть: смотрим PID tar'а, идем в /proc/PID/fd, находим, какой из тамошних симлинков показывает на архив, запоминаем его имя (например, "3"), переходим в /proc/PID/fdinfo, делаем «cat 3», в строке pos: видим текущую позицию в архиве.

Comment: В целом работает, только как узнать, куда указывает симлинк из fd?

Comment: @Qwertiy, [номера стандартных потоков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8). но значение после pos в fdinfo, насколько я вижу, отлично от нуля далеко не всегда. ещё точнее: протестировал на нескольких версиях/сборках программы linux, и ни на одной в процессе работы ни для одного из дескрипторов (в т.ч. нестандартного, с номером больше 2), цифра ни разу не отличалась от 0. возможно, зависит ещё и от текущей конфигурации программы linux.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я проверил на `md5sum sda1.img`, дескриптор был 3, значение менялось корректно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но стандартных потоков всего 3, а файлов открытых потенциально может быть много.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ещё поэкспериментировал. если запускать `$ md5sum файл`, то в fdinfo строка с pos меняется. а если что-нибудь вроде `$ blabla | md5sum`, то во всех fdinfo в строке pos — нули. дальше разбираться — лень.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, судя по всему у стандартных потоков всегда нули...

Answer (score 4):

можно вставить в «трубу» между процессами ещё один элемент, подсчитывающий и выводящий в *stderr* проходящие сквозь него байты.

одна из таких программ — [`pv`](https://packages.debian.org/ru/stretch/pv).

пример использования (приведён и пример вывода в процессе работы):

```
$ tar -xzOf архив | pv | md5sum
1.26GiB 0:00:06 [ 194MiB/s] [        <=>                                      ]
```

---

программа может отображать и «проценты выполнения», но для этого ей надо знать размер файла. т.е., она должна быть инициатором «трубы». пример такого запуска:

```
$ pv архив | tar -xzO - | md5sum
1.01GiB 0:00:05 [ 213MiB/s] [==========================>    ] 80% ETA 0:00:01
```

---

чтобы программа *pv* подсчитывала не количество байт, а количество символов перевода строки, ей нужно передать опцию `-l` (`--line-mode`).

---

доп. чтение:

- [`$ man pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)

Comment: Хороший вариант, но о таком надо задуматься до запуска команды, а не после. И ещё вопрос - а на производительность она не сильно влияет?

Comment: *на производительность она не сильно влияет?* — я думаю, что на производительность программы md5sum (а именно она является главным «тормозом» в используемой «трубе») программа pv не оказывает никакого влияния. а если (вдруг) главный «тормоз» — файловая система, так тем более. // да, конечно, дополнительные такты процессора расходуются на подсчёты/передачи. так что если у вас процессор загружен всеми своими ядрами под завязку, то какие-то дополнительные микросекунды придётся подождать.

Comment: По скриншоту с процессорным временем на md5 уходит в 4 раза меньше, чем на gzip. Но вообще да, скорее всего там в скорость диска упрётся, а не в процессор.