# Подсчитать количество строк stdout внутри pipe

Tags: linux, счетчики, pipes

Генератор выводит огромное количество строк в трубу, затем идет многократная и длительная обработка строк, процесс весьма долгий. Известно заранее точное количество комбинаций-строк выходящих из генератора в трубу. Можно ли как-то в реальном времени отслеживать количество строк, уже вышедших из генератора, но еще не до конца обработанных всеми процессами (дабы не подгружать систему и не сильно тормозить весь процесс, возможно с какой-то периодичностью или скажем каждый полный миллион комбинаций к примеру). То есть воткнуть какой-то счетчик строк в разрыв трубы, чтобы в терминале отслеживать ход процесса

`generator | счетчик | process1 | process2 | process3`

буду признателен за любые предложения, главное чтобы не сильно подгружали и были не слишком трудоемки (большой точности не требуется, оценить можно и на глаз, достаточно просто подсчета кол-ва строк без %% уже вышедших в трубу)
Желательно не привязываться к количеству исходных комбинаций если это возможно, так как не всегда это известно. Спасибо

Comment: [`pv -l`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803499/178576)

Comment: Есть волшебная команда `tee`, которая в дополнение к стандартному выводу, пишет в файл. На примере rsync: `rsync -avz --dry-run ~ /tmp/ | tee /tmp/pipe-progress | sort` будет работать долго. В другой консоли можно глянуть в `/tmp/pipe-progress`. Ну и если нужен какой-то прогресс, `watch wc -l /tmp/pipe-progress` в другой консоли покажет количество строк - каждые 2 секунды (`man watch`)

Comment: @alexander barakin - как всегда, то, что нужно!